# The inputs into BERT are token IDs. How do I get the corresponding the input token VECTORs into BERT?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, word-embedding

I am new and learning about transformers.

In a lot of BERT tutorials, I see the input is just the token id of the words. But surely we need to convert this token ID to a vector representation (it can be one hot encoding, or any initial vector representation for each token ID) so that it can be used by the model.

My question is: Where cam I find this initial vector representation for each token?

Comment: Hi, in the current state of the question, I believe that you could probably get a (theoretically correct) answer on [stats.se]. Otherwise, please feel free to include a more specific piece of code, which gives us a general idea which specific model you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BERT, the input is a `string` itself. THen, BERT manages to convert it into a token and then, create its vector. Let's see an example:

```py
prep_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3'
enc_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4' 
bert_preprocess = hub.KerasLayer(prep_url)
bert_encoder = hub.KerasLayer(enc_url)

text = ['Hello I"m new to stack overflow']

# First, you need to preprocess the data

preprocessed_text = bert_preprocess(text)
# this will give you a dict with a few keys such us input_word_ids, that is, the tokenizer

encoded = bert_encoder(preprocessed_text)
# and this will give you the (1, 768) vector with the context value of the previous text. the output is encoded['pooled_output']

# you can play with both dicts, printing its keys()
```

I recommend you to go to both links above and do a little of research. To recap, BERT uses string as inputs and then tokenize it (with its own tokenzer!). If you want to tokenize with the same values, you need the same vocab file, but for a fresh start like you are doing this should be enough.

Comment: Thanks! So it seems like the input is literally the token IDs. Is there some kind of benefit to use the token ids instead of the other methods like bag of words, one hot encoding e.t.c? Was confused because of this. Like why token ids? Its like an ordinal encoding scheme where you represent words as ids

Comment: @woowz the encoder input is not only the token IDs. It has other layers, I recommend you to follow my code to check out, but yes, the mos important thing there are the token IDs. And, that token is like a bag of words, but deeper. It has concatenation words (for example ##ing) and reserved words such as [CLS]. All of them are included in the vocab file